# Conditionally formatting A LOT of text columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, conditional-formatting

Please help me to create conditional formatting for multiple text columns. I understand that I can format them by creating a separate measure for each column, which I started doing, but this will take too long.
Currently this is what I have:

```
Status color Column_1=
var selected_status = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Column_1])
return
if(selected_status= "CLOSED", "#FF0000",
    if(selected_status="YES", "#F4D03F",
        if(selected_status="NO", "#D5D8DC", "#FDFEFE")))

Status color Column_2=
var selected_status = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Column_2])
return
if(selected_status= "CLOSED", "#FF0000",
    if(selected_status="YES", "#F4D03F",
        if(selected_status="NO", "#D5D8DC", "#FDFEFE")))
```

etc.

But I have almost 50 columns, I don't want to manually create 50 measures, and to apply each specific measure to each specific column.
How can I apply this conditional formatting logic to ALL of the 50 text columns

Thanks